# perform arithmetic operations in sql when using cast

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, casting

I have table for salary. In this salary field I add Lacks and thousands in a single column.So I want to use select statement.

**My query is**

```
SELECT TOP(10) 'INSERT INTO jobs(Budget) VALUES('+
CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(r.Budget AS VARCHAR(50)), 0, 
PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget))*100000 AS VARCHAR(50))
+ ',' +CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(r.Budget AS VARCHAR(50)), PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget) + 4,
patindex('%Thousands%', r.Budget) - PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget) - 4)* 1000  AS 
VARCHAR(50))+')'
FROM dbo.requirementsdetailsfororganization r
```

**Output**

```
INSERT INTO jobs(Budget) VALUES(0,85000)
INSERT INTO jobs(Budget) VALUES(200000,5000)
```

Here `I want to add lacks and thousands`, it means i want to add

- 0,85000 =85000
- 200000,5000=205000

  in the above query.

Any one have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The output query has one column specified in the jobs table that will be loaded called Budget.  The VALUES clause includes two values.  This should throw the following error:

```
Msg 110, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.
```

If you change your code to this, then the insert will work.  However, it will simply populate two columns with data and not add the values together:

```
SELECT TOP(10) 'INSERT INTO jobs(Budgetm Lacks) VALUES('+

CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(r.Budget AS VARCHAR(50)), 0, PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget))*100000 AS VARCHAR(50))
      + ',' +CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(r.Budget AS VARCHAR(50)), PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget) + 4
     ,patindex('%Thousands%', r.Budget) - PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget) - 4)* 1000  AS 
   VARCHAR(50))+')'
FROM dbo.requirementsdetailsfororganization r
```

If you want to add the two columns together in a Total column, then you could use this code:

```
SELECT TOP(10) 'INSERT INTO jobs(Budgetm Lacks) VALUES('+

CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(r.Budget AS VARCHAR(50)), 0, PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget))*100000 AS VARCHAR(50))
      + ',' +CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(r.Budget AS VARCHAR(50)), PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget) + 4
     ,patindex('%Thousands%', r.Budget) - PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget) - 4)* 1000  AS 
   VARCHAR(50)) + CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(r.Budget AS VARCHAR(50)), 0, PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget))*100000 AS VARCHAR(50))
      + ' + ' +CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(r.Budget AS VARCHAR(50)), PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget) + 4
     ,patindex('%Thousands%', r.Budget) - PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget) - 4)* 1000  AS 
       VARCHAR(50)) + ')'
FROM dbo.requirementsdetailsfororganization r
```

This would populate a third column with the sum of the two columns.  If you are only trying to populate the Budget column with the sum of the two columns and not have separate columns, then you just need to change the comma to a + sign in your VALUES clause.

```
SELECT TOP(10) 'INSERT INTO jobs(Budget) VALUES('+

CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(r.Budget AS VARCHAR(50)), 0, PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget))*100000 AS VARCHAR(50))
      + '+' +CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(r.Budget AS VARCHAR(50)), PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget) + 4
     ,patindex('%Thousands%', r.Budget) - PATINDEX('%laks%', r.Budget) - 4)* 1000  AS     VARCHAR(50))+')'
FROM dbo.requirementsdetailsfororganization r
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But I edit my question. I want to add two values in a single column. i don't want to display the two values and + symbol. + symbol i denote for add operation.